# uWSGI doesn't execute chdir

Tags: linux, debian, uwsgi

Title. When I run uwsgi as `uwsgi ***` or `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi ***` it works perfectly, but when I run it as `/usr/bin/uwsgi ***` (as it being runned as service) it doesn't execute `chdir` directive of `.ini` file what results in impossibility to load the script.

My `.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
pidfile = /run/uwsgi/app/***.pid
chdir = /var/www/admin/data/www/test.***.##/***/
pythonpath = ..
file = wsgi.py
```

`default.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
autoload = true
master = true
workers = 2
no-orphans = true
log-date = true
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a different program, you'll get different results.  `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` and `/usr/bin/uwsgi` are different programs.  My first thought would be that `/usr/bin/uwsgi` is perhaps an older version, which doesn't support the `chdir` parameter.

Comment: Yes, you was right, there was an old version from debian repositories in `/usr/bin/uwsgi` and new version which was installed by `pip` in `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`. Service still doesn't start, but it's another problem already. Thanks!